# how are callbacks being called after the fact?

Tags: javascript

In the following code,  I don't understand why both callback functions are being called.  callback01 makes sense because it's in the callbacks array before the call to load.  callback02 on the other hand, it's not put into the array until after the call to load yet the console shows it being called.

```
var callbacks = [];

function addCallback(func) {
  callbacks.push(func);
}

function load(img_url) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    console.log('loaded.');
    callbacks.forEach(function(func) { func(); } )
  };
  img.src = img_url;
}

addCallback(function() { console.log('callback01'); });
load('img/image01.png');
addCallback(function() { console.log('callback02'); });
```

Comment: The image didn't load yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research into the event loop of the browser that javascript runs in, it seems that what happen is this:

Since javascript is executed in a single thread, when the code is executing, control isn't returned back to the browser for processing events until all of that code has been executed.

The img.onload callback is inserted into the event queue, the addCallBack for callback02 is executed adding itself to the array and it's at this point that control returns from javascript back to the event loop with both callbacks available when the onload callback is called.

```
var callbacks = [];

function addCallback(func) {
  console.log('addCallback: ' + (new Date()));
  callbacks.push(func);
}

function load(img_url) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    console.log('load:  ' + (new Date()));
    callbacks.forEach(function(func) { func(); } )
  };
  img.src = img_url;
}

function badsleep(duration) {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  while((new Date()).getTime() < (now + duration));
}

addCallback(function() { console.log('callback01: ' + (new Date())); });
load('img/image01.png');
badsleep(2000);
addCallback(function() { console.log('callback02: ' + (new Date())); });

console.log('execution continues: ' + (new Date()));
```

results in:

```
addCallback: Sat Jul 05 2014 08:56:05
addCallback: Sat Jul 05 2014 08:56:07
execution continues: Sat Jul 05 2014 08:56:07
load:  Sat Jul 05 2014 08:56:07
callback01: Sat Jul 05 2014 08:56:07
callback02: Sat Jul 05 2014 08:56:07
```

So it seems that this is reason both callbacks are in the array despite appearing to be added before and after the load function.  I hope it is anyway, because this makes the code straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Both callbacks fire because the callbacks fire after the image loads.  It takes a few milliseconds for the image to load, which is plenty of time for the code to load and add both callbacks.

Presumably this is how the browser is executing your code:

```
// 1 - add first callback
addCallback(function() { console.log('callback01'); });

// 2 - tell JS to begin loading
load('img/image01.png');

// 3 - add second callback
addCallback(function() { console.log('callback02'); });

// 4 - image loads in the background
// 5 - the img.onload function fires and invokes each callback
// 5.a - callback 1 fires
// 5.b - callback 2 fires
```

Comment: So it's just arbitrary?  If the image loaded fast enough, callback02 may not get called?

Comment: @stewsims, exactly. Especially if it comes from the browser's cache.

Comment: Correct.  If the callback hasn't been added in time, the callback won't be invoked.  There are libraries that handle that type of logic for you, like jQuery's Deferreds, but if I recommend you get the basics first before moving there.

Comment: Thanks! For now I'll just make sure things are set as they should be  before calling load and avoid unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The second addCallback line has probably completed by the time load() completes. If you don't want callback02 available at that point, add it at the end of the load() function definition (if that is an option).

Comment: *Javascript runs asynchronously, unlike languages like PHP which are serialized.* Sorry, that part of your answer is absolutely wrong.

Comment: it isn't 'absolutely wrong' but it is admittedly an over generalization. The point was the issue is likely due to the firing order being different then the OP expected, and if the OP is expecting php-like behavior, JS won't deliver that with things like .onload.

Comment: Well, that's true. But there is nothing inherently async in Javascript, it's the environment the code usually runs in that enforces asynchronous patterns. Javascript is "serial" in nature, just like PHP is. And likewise, you can do async in PHP if you want it.

Comment: Fair enough and thanks for clarifying the issue. I'll remove that line and upvote your comments. Thanks.